# Changing the default contact group when using Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: iphone, contacts, exchange-activesync

I have an iPhone 3GS (with the latest iOS version). It syncs with the corporate Exchange server.

But when I am saving contacts (from the recent calls list for example), there is no way to set where the contact is saved. (I have a couple of Contacts folders in the Exchange account).

Is there a way to tell the iPhone where to save new contacts either when I save the new contact or just to set the default contact group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5.1, you can define a "Default Account" for Contacts in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Scroll down until you see a Contacts heading; Default Account is at the bottom of that section. This setting will affect where new Contacts created on the iPhone are placed.